# »Dem« zusammen mit dem substantivierten Verb »stattfinden«

Tags: grammatical-case

Ich habe im [Wörterbuch](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/schwaenzen) das Wort *Stattfindendem* gefunden. Ich kenne das trennbare Verb *stattfinden.* Ich kann nachvollziehen, dass *das Stattfinden* ein substantiviertes Verb ist. Warum gibt es das Wort *Stattfindendem?* Was bedeutet das Wort? Hat es mit dem Dativ zu tun?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Das ist eine Substantivierung des Adjektivs *stattfindend* das wiederum vom Verb *stattfinden* abstammt:

> Nominativ: **Etwas Stattfindendes** macht mehr Freude als etwas Abgesagtes.
> Dativ: An **etwas Stattfindendem** hat man mehr Freude als an etwas Abgesagtem.

Comment: Das Adjektiv auf der Zwischenstufe ist natürlich zunächst einmal ein Partizip

Comment: Die Beispiele sind wirklich erhellend. Welches Gedankens ich mich nicht erwehren kann: Genitiv und "etwas" scheinen unvereinbar. Mein Denkfehler?

Comment: @Wolf: Da ist kein Genitiv, das ist Nominativ Singular Neutrum. Wie es auch davor steht.

Comment: @HalvarF das habe ich schon gesehen, ich spreche von einem der Fälle, die in der Liste der Beispiele hier *nicht* stehen. Akkusativ ist klar *Über **etwas Stattfindendes** freue ich mich mehr als über etwas Abgesagtes.* Genitiv mit "etwas" bleibt für mich weiter offen ...

Comment: @Wolf: Ah so - naja, wie jedes Adjektiv: "Etwas Stattfindenden kann man sich mehr erfreuen als etwas Abgesagten"; "Aufgrund etwas im Pool Schwimmenden rief Frau von Bülow die Polizei an."

Comment: @HalvarF Danke für die Hilfe. Es fühlt sich irgendwie richtig, aber eben doch wirklich sehr unbehaglich an. Läuft einem in der Praxis vermutlich schon seit Jahrzehnten nicht mehr über den Weg ...

Answer (score 4):

> stattfindend

ist das Partizip I von "stattfinden". Dieses Partizip wird wie ein Adjektiv benutzt und gebeugt:

> singen => der singende Koch

> Besuchen Sie den morgen **stattfindenden** Vortrag.

Dieses Partizip I kann man, wie jedes Adjektiv, auch substantivieren:

> Auf dem Bahnsteig am Bahnhof stehen viele **Wartende**.

> In meinem Kalender für Dezember steht wegen der Pandemie mehr Ausfallendes als **Stattfindendes**.
> An etwas noch **Stattfindendem** *(Dativ Singular Neutrum)*
> nehme ich meist nicht teil.

Der Unterschied zum substantivierten Verb ist, dass das substantivierte Verb den Vorgang selbst bezeichnet:

> Das Warten auf den Zug kann lang werden.
> Das Stattfinden unseres Workshops ist noch nicht sicher.

Das substantivierte Partizip I dagegen bezeichnet jemanden oder etwas, der/die/das die Tätigkeit ausführt, die das Verb beschreibt.

Beispiel: Das substantivierte Partizip I von "warten" bezeichnet Personen, die warten:

> Viele Wartende lesen auf ihrem Telefon.

Das substantivierte Partizip I von "stattfinden" bezeichnet Termine, Veranstaltungen etc., die stattfinden:

> Bei noch Stattfindendem müssen die Corana-Bestimmungen eingehalten werden.